# Clustering in Python: Difference in result due to use of matrix vs data frame?Why is this happening?

Tags: python, numpy, cluster-analysis

In calculating the difference between each data point and the center of its assigned cluster and squaring it then summing up, i tried using two different approaches

The sample1 approach use a matrix X and the sample2 approach uses the orignal dataframe.

I cannot seem to understand why are the results different?

Can anyone explain?

```
ageinc_df:
   income  age  z_income     z_age
0  101743   58  0.550812  1.693570
1   49597   27 -0.777331 -1.130565
2   36517   52 -1.110474  1.146963
3   33223   49 -1.194372  0.873660
4   72994   53 -0.181416  1.238064
```

```
#Sample1
X = ageinc_df[['z_income','z_age']].as_matrix()
cluster_assignments = model.fit_predict(X)
centers = model.cluster_centers_

import numpy as np
#Following line is in question
print(np.sum((X - centers[cluster_assignments]) ** 2))
```

results in just 1189.7476232504307

vs
(in the following i decided not use the X matrix)

```
#Sample2
cluster_assignments1 = model.fit_predict(ageinc_df[['z_income','z_age']])
centers = model.cluster_centers_

import numpy as np

#matrix is replaced by dataframe
print(np.sum( (ageinc_df[['z_income','z_age']] - centers[cluster_assignments1]) ** 2))
```

results in:
z_income    191.516452
z_age       998.231171

Answer (score 2):

If you look to the second result, you have 191.51 + 998.2311 = 1189.74 and you find back the first result.

When you work on matrix, `np.sum` add all the coefficients, on row and colums. You need to use the option axis if you want so sum only on a special axis.

In you code on dataframe, it's going to sum by columns : as you have labels on the columns, the function doesn't naturally mix the quantities.